# How to invoke a screen when flutter_local_notification is triggered?

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I have implemented a scheduled notification using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). How to perform a function or invoke a screen when a scheduled notification is triggered?

Comment: do you mean after clicking notification?

Comment: No,  In short, I can say like an Alarm App, Need to invoke a screen at a specific time when the app is closed something like this.